# Auto-refreshing pages in Chrome : CSS for iframe not loaded sometimes

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

In brief, I have a web page which has an iframe (internal source) and it is refreshing every 15 seconds. The problem is that sometimes, after refreshing, the content of the iframe is not visible. Actually, the content is loading but not applying styles from the main style sheet. This is happening only in Chrome browser, it works fine in other browsers.

What I tried is :

1/ Add code to stop use browser cache

```
 header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
 header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

> result: Not success

2/ Add CSS when loading the iframe

```
     $('iframe').load( function() {
            $('iframe').contents().find("head")
              .append($("<style type='text/css'>  #table tr,th{ color: red !important;}  </style>"));
    });
```

> result: Not success

Note: when I check the response header, it is **`304 Not Modified`** all time when the iframe is getting blank. Otherwise it is **`200 OK`**.

**Question:**  Is there anyway to stop getting this response "304 Not Modified" header? I need to get fresh response without using the cache? Or else any solution to prevent this issue?